# Converter números romanos em Java

Tags: java

Fiz um programa que converte números inteiros para números romanos em Java, mas o programa não executa.

O que pode ser?

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numero, i;
        int vaNum[]= {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

        String vaRom[] = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

        while(true){

            numero = teclado.nextInt();
            if(numero == 0)
                break;
            System.out.printf("%-4d", numero);
            i=0;
            while(numero>0){
            if(numero >= vaNum[i]){
                System.out.println(vaRom[i]);
                numero = numero - vaNum[i];
            }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Acho que tudo q vc precisa é dos símbolos primários dos números romanos(I,v,x,L,c, d e m) e quanto eles representam em decimais e depois em quais posições eles aparecem quando agrupados. Fazendo isso, fica fácil converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você esqueceu de incrementar o `i` dentro do `while` interno quando o número não pode ser subtraído. Isso faz com que esse `while` interno seja infinito.

Também havia uns pequenos problemas de usar `System.out.println` ao invés de `System.out.print`, o que acrescentaria quebras-de-linha após cada caractere.

Veja aqui o seu código corrigido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] vaNum = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

        String[] vaRom = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

        while (true) {

            int numero = teclado.nextInt();
            if (numero == 0) break;
            System.out.printf("%-4d ", numero);
            int i = 0;
            while (numero > 0) {
                if (numero >= vaNum[i]) {
                    System.out.print(vaRom[i]);
                    numero -= vaNum[i];
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Dado esta entrada:

```
4999
237
88
23
0
```

Ele produz esta saída:

```
4999 MMMMCMXCIX
237  CCXXXVII
88   LXXXVIII
23   XXIII
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/g6HM0v)